# hyperv - Clone VM, wont clone come up w same IPs and make a networking collision?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Existing VM is running in prod.
Did an export, then an import to clone it.
Clone is currently in stopped state.... I am almost afraid to fire it up!

What is best step now to get the OS up (without connecting to network), get the IPs set to unique, and then to bring up all the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the VM on a separate subnet/vswitch (or whatever Hyper-V calls it) that is isolated from the rest of your network.

Answer (score 1):

- Open up the settings of the Hyper-V virtual machine
- Navigate to the network adapter and configure as "Not connected"
- If needed, I would determine the MAC address of the NIC on the existing server, and configure the cloned VM one to match it by setting the MAC address to static from the Network Adapter settings.
- Power on the virtual machine and adjust the settings as appropriate.
- Re-assign the virtual network on the NIC to the proper, original, virtual network.